# Método para verificar três objetos de cada vez

Tags: java, jsf

Trabalho com Java e JSF. Tenho uma lista de 27 objetos e tenho um método, chamado a cada 20 segundos através de *polling*, que atualiza um campo desses objetos.

Por motivos bastante específicos, eu preciso que esse método faça a atualização de três em três objetos.

Ou seja, atualizar três objetos, encerrar o método e na próxima vez que o *polling* chamar o método, ele deve atualizar os três objetos seguintes.

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar colocar em algum *managed bean* anotado com `PageScoped` ou `SessionScoped`, uma variável do tipo `int` (vamos chamá-la de `indice`) que conta a partir de qual objeto deve iniciar a verificação.

O método que faz a verificação (que também está neste *managed bean*) acessa a lista de objetos, obtém os três objetos pertinentes e faz um `indice += 3;`. É importante também colocar-se pelo menos um `if` em algum lugar deste método para se certificar que não está se tentando acessar a lista além dos limites, o que é importante para o caso de a lista já ter acabado ou tiver menos que três objetos restantes.

Quando todos os objetos tiverem sido verificados, você pode fazer um `indice = 0;` para ele recomeçar o processo. Ou então executar alguma outra ação que você julgue pertinente.

Fique atento para o caso em que algum elemento ser inserido ou excluído da lista (supondo que haja algum caso assim), caso contrário isso poderia bagunçar com a sua verificação.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, colocando o meu managed bean como PageScope ou SessionScope, a variável que eu criei, indice, não perdera o valor sempre que o meu poll fizer uma nova chamada no método, é isso?

Comment: @Jason Sim, com o `PageScoped` ou `SessionScoped` o bean, incluindo todos os valores nele guardado, vai sobreviver de uma requisição para outra.

Comment: Obrigado, acho que dará certo, irei implementar.

Comment: @Jason Caso funcione, não se esqueça de marcar a minha resposta como aceita (o "v" verde à esquerda abaixo da pontuação da resposta). Caso não funcione, me diga o que aconteceu e vamos ver como resolver.

Comment: Ok farei isso...